# On scroll down images are moving up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, scroll

I want on scroll down, that the images are moving up a bit, like on this website:

[example site](https://digitaldoes.com/blog/lotus-7-days-of-creation/) (digital does)

[image: Images example]

Down the website on digitaldoes you can see what i mean. The images are moving up a bit if you scroll down. Is it maby a lazy-load with images that are fading in or an animation where the images moving for example 5px up?

Here is a:  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L8sdpqzk/2/) **updated!!!**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $(".img-scroll").css("display", "none");
    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $( ".img-scroll" ).addClass("animate");
        $( ".img-scroll" ).css("display", "block");
        console.log("Hey");
    });
    
});
```

```css
.img-scroll {
  -moz-transition: top 10s;
  transition: top 10s;
}


.img-scroll.animate {
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <header class="arbeiten">
    <h2>{ Logos }</h2>
  </header>
</div>

<div id="links">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xxl-1"></div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xxl-5">
      <div class="card shadow-sm first-image">
        <a href="https://www.fillmurray.com/1000/1000" title="Test - Logo #1">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/150" alt="Test - Logo #1" class="card-img-top logo-hover">
        </a>

        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Test - Logo #1</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xxl-5">
      <div class="card shadow-sm">
        <a href="https://www.fillmurray.com/1000/1000" title="Test - Logo #2">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/150" alt="Test - Logo #2" class="card-img-top logo-hover">
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Test - Logo #2</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xxl-5 img-scroll">
        <div class="card shadow-sm first-image">
          <a href="https://www.fillmurray.com/1000/1000" title="Test - Logo #3">
            <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/150" alt="Test - Logo #3" class="card-img-top logo-hover">
          </a>

          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Test - Logo #3</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xxl-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xxl-1"></div>

    </div>
    
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

I hope, someone can help me...

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+parallax+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: Thanks, but i do not know, how to call it (in my search). It is not a parallax effect. That, what i mean is more down the site. The images are moving up a bit.

Comment: That is called parallax. https://www.wix.com/blog/2019/08/what-is-parallax-scrolling-explained-with-examples/

Comment: Are you sure? I mean only the images down the site. On top of the site this is parallax, but this is not what i mean.

Comment: Is it maby lazy load(image and fade).. with an animation on scroll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important step is to check if an `<img>` element is entering the current viewport.

We can use the [Intersection Observer API.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

```
const options = {
  rootMargin: "0px",
  threshold: 0.5
};

const inViewPortObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      let target = entry.target;
      let dataSrc = target.getAttribute('data-src');
      target.src = dataSrc;
      target.classList.replace('lazyload', 'lazyloaded');
    }
  });
}, options);
```

By adjusting the threshold value we can define when the intersecting value returns true:
E.g `treshold:0.5` => element is intersection if 50% of it's height is in viewport.

Now we can define a callback:
`if(entry.isIntersecting){}`
If element is in viewport – set the `src` attribute from `data-src` and toggle css classes from 'lazyload' to 'lazyloaded'.

Most lazyload libraries use a similar syntax or api concept like this:

```
<img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/480/480" class="lazyload">
```

The actual image src/URL is defined by a data attribute: `data-src`.
Lazy loading can significantly improve the overall performance and user experience by loading images only if they are really required.

The animation is done by toggling between css classes:
E.g `.lazyload` (not loaded yet) and `lazyloaded` (loaded)

```
.lazyload {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
}

.lazyloaded {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

#### Simple Example: using  js IntersectionObserver()

```js
const options = {
  rootMargin: "0px",
  threshold: 0.5
};

const inViewPortObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      let target = entry.target;
      let dataSrc = target.getAttribute('data-src');
      target.src = dataSrc;
      target.classList.replace('lazyload', 'lazyloaded');
    }
  });
}, options);

const images = document.querySelectorAll('.lazyload');
images.forEach(function(img, i) {
  inViewPortObserver.observe(img);
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

header {
  margin-bottom: 40vmin;
}

main {
  padding-bottom: 50em;
}

section {
  margin-bottom: 20em;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.row>* {
  flex: 1;
}

.card-img-top {
  transition: 2s;
}

.lazyload {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.lazyloaded {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

img {
  aspect-ratio: 2/1;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <header class="arbeiten">
    <h2>{ Logos }</h2>
    <p>Please scroll down …</p>
  </header>
</div>

<main>
  <section>
    <div class="row">
      <figure>
        <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/480/480" alt="Test - Logo #1" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/150" alt="Test - Logo #1" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
      </figure>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <figure>
        <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/200" alt="Test - Logo #1" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="Test - Logo #1" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/400/240" alt="Test - Logo #1" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="row">
      <figure>
        <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/320/240" alt="Test - Logo #1" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
      </figure>

      <figure>
        <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/150" alt="Test - Logo #1" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/333/111" alt="Test - Logo #1" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/444/333" alt="Test - Logo #1" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

#### Example 2: observe a parent element and lazyload images

The main difference: we're observing viewport intersections for parent elements like the `.card` class.

```js
const options = {
  rootMargin: "0px",
  threshold: 0.1
};

const inViewPortObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      let target = entry.target;
      let img = target.querySelector('img');
      let dataSrc = img.getAttribute('data-src');
      img.src = dataSrc;
      target.classList.add('inViewPort');
    }
  });
}, options);

const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
cards.forEach(function(card, i) {
  inViewPortObserver.observe(card);
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

header {
  margin-bottom: 60vmin;
}

main {
  padding-bottom: 50em;
}

section {
  margin-bottom: 20em;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}

.row>* {
  flex: 1;
}

.card {
  transition: 2s;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  border: 2px solid red;
  opacity: 0;
}


/** optional sibling delay */

.row .card:nth-of-type(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.row .card:nth-of-type(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.75s;
}

.row .card:nth-of-type(4) {
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.row .card:nth-of-type(5) {
  transition-delay: 1.25s;
}

.row .card:nth-of-type(6) {
  transition-delay: 1.5s;
}

.inViewPort {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

img {
  aspect-ratio: 2/1;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <header class="arbeiten">
    <h2>{ Logos }</h2>
    <p>Please scroll down …</p>
  </header>
</div>

<main>
  <section>
    <div class="row row1">
      <div class="card">
        <a href="#">
          <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/480/480" alt="" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <a href="#">
          <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/150" alt="" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
        </a>
      </div>
      
      <div class="card">
        <a href="#">
          <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/222" alt="" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
        </a>
      </div>
      
      <div class="card">
        <a href="#">
          <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/247" alt="" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
        </a>
      </div>
      
      
    </div>
  </section>


  <section>
    <div class="row row2">
      <div class="card">
        <a href="#">
          <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/320/240" alt="" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <a href="#">
          <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/111" alt="" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <a href="#">
          <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/112" alt="" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <section>
    <div class="row row2">
      <div class="card">
        <a href="#">
          <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/320/240" alt="" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <a href="#">
          <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/111" alt="" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <a href="#">
          <img data-src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/112" alt="" class="lazyload card-img-top logo-hover">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Thanks for you anwser!! The animation and lazyload is working, but I have got an a-tag thats surround the img-tag and the a-tag has got a border. The border is now there and the image is flying in(animation). Here is a Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/T91dZds

Comment: <a href="../img/test-01.png" title="test - Logo #1">
                    <img data-src="../img/test-01-thumb.png" alt="test- Logo #1" class="image-border card-img-top logo-hover lazyload">
                  </a>

Comment: or it is the card, who has got the border

Comment: @c00L: I've added a new example. It's basically just binding the "in viewport" check to the parent element (in your case the .card class or the parent a element).  Does it work as expected? Just for fun - and to illustrate you might not need heavy libraries I've also added some simple delay properties for asynchronous fly in effects.

Comment: Thanks @herrstrietzel!! It is working as expected now. :D
The delay is not working, the images are flying at the same speed. Do not know, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @c00L: probably there's something wrong with your selectors (e.g. your actual HTML might have additional nestings). Inspect the elements in devTools to check the delay properties - there might also be an overriding css rule.

Answer (score 1):

They have build the gallery with gridster and scrollmagic. Scrollmagic lets you do all kind of things when scrolling.

you can checkout the package at https://scrollmagic.io

Answer (score 0):

You can animate with jQuery. Here is tutorial with [example](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/demo/demo_move-elements-on-page-scroll-using-jquery-and-css.php).

- http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/move-elements-on-page-scroll-using-jquery-and-css.php

Answer (score 0):

The animation on the site that you provided is triggered when the [`load`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) event on the images is emitted. The `load` event is emitted when an image has completed loading. This is combined with [lazy loading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading#images_and_iframes) to load the images as you scroll down on the page.

To implement something like this, you need to enable lazy loading for the images and listen for a `load` event on them. When the load event is emitted, use Javascript to complete the animation.

The javascript would look something like this:

```js
$(".img-scroll").one("load", () => {
    // do animation here
})
```

Just make sure the images have lazy loading enabled by setting their `loading` attribute to `lazy`

Answer (score 0):

there is a very good **library for scroll effect called AOS**.I linked it down here
it .You can find setup guide at the end of the page. Just **add those styles to your image or any other html tag**!. Make sure that you check it out.

[link to AOS library](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/)

Answer (score 0):

I am using TweenMax.min.js, TimelineMax.min.js, ScrollMagic.min.js

- List item

```js
const tl = new TimelineMax();
const tl2 = new TimelineMax();
const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

tl.from('#first-fig', .3, {y:200, opacity: 0});
tl.from('#second-fig', .3, {scale: 0}, "=-.5");
tl.from('#third-fig', .3, {y:200, opacity: 0});

tl2.from('#fourth-fig', .5, {y:200, opacity: 0});
tl2.from('#fifth-fig', .5, {y:200,opacity: 0});
tl2.from('#sixth-fig', .5, {y:200, opacity: 0});

const firstScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: "#second-h1"
})
  .setTween(tl)
        .addTo(controller);

const secondScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: "#first-img"
})
  .setTween(tl2)
        .addTo(controller);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arapey");
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Arapey";
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #dfe6e9;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6rem;
}

.section--1 {
  height: 100rem;
  background: #bdc3c7;
}

.section--2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100rem;
}

.images {
  display: grid;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 25rem);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0.8rem;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 25rem;
}
.images--img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TimelineMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <section class="section--1">
    <h1>Scroll down to see the animations</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="section--2">
    <h1 id="second-h1">
      hello there I love code and music
    </h1>
    <div class="images">
      <figure class="images--fig" id="first-fig"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485170536212-67180b105ff6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="" class="images--img" id="first-img"></figure>
      <figure class="images--fig" id="second-fig"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518257678582-d5c9bb2e6ec9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=588&q=80" alt="" class="images--img"></figure>
      <figure class="images--fig" id="third-fig"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1540821924489-7690c70c4eac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=991&q=80" alt="" class="images--img"></figure>
      <figure class="images--fig" id="fourth-fig"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484755560615-a4c64e778a6c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=980&q=80" alt="" class="images--img" id="fourth-img"></figure>
      <figure class="images--fig" id="fifth-fig"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1481207727306-1a9f151fca7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="" class="images--img"></figure>
      <figure class="images--fig" id="sixth-fig">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517852058149-07c7a2e65cc6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="" class="images--img">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section--1"></section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is barebone structure similar to the example website using a tiny library [@opuu/inview](https://github.com/opuu/InView).

The parallax effect and animation on scroll both can be done with this same library very easily.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#background {
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/700/500');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 150vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#foreground {
  background-color: blue;
  transition: margin-top 0.1s;
  height: 200vh;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#effect {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: brown;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.aos {
  transform: translateY(500px);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.aos.active {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#empty {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
    <div id="container">
        <div id="background">
            Background with image
        </div>
        <div id="foreground">
            Content that overlays the background
        </div>
        <div id="effect">
            <img class="aos" loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/700/500" alt="">
            <img class="aos" loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/700/500" alt="">
        </div>
        <div id="effect">
            <img class="aos" loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/700/500" alt="">
            <img class="aos" loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/700/500" alt="">
        </div>
        <div id="empty">

        </div>
    </div>
    
        <script type="module">
        import InView from "https://unpkg.com/@opuu/inview@1.0.2/dist/inview.js";

        let hero = new InView("#background");

        hero.on("enter", (event) => {
            document.querySelector("#foreground").style.marginTop = `-${100 - event.percentage}vh`;
        });

        let effect = new InView(".aos");
        let queue = 0;
        effect.on("enter", (event) => {
            if (queue == 0) {
                event.target.style.transitionDelay = "0.2s";
                event.target.classList.add("active");
                queue = 1;
            } else {
                event.target.classList.add("active");
                queue = 0;
            }
        });

        // effect.on('exit', (event) => {
        //     event.target.classList.remove("active"); // you can also add remove animation
        // });
    </script>
```

*Note: I am the author of this library.*